# Django composite unique on multiple model fields

Tags: django, django-models

Let us say I have a model for social network posts, users and likes:

```py
class Post(models.Model):
    submitter = models.ForeignKey(User, null=False, default=None)
    content = models.CharField()
    date = models.DateField()

    with_likes = PostLikeCountManager()
    objects = models.Manager()

class Like(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    post = models.ForeignKey(Post)
    time = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
```

It would be helpful to think of `Post` model as representing a `Facebook` post. Now, I would like to limit one like per post per user. How do I achieve that? One way would be to create a composite primary key on (`user`, `post`) attributes of `Like` class. I don't know how to achieve that in Django. The other would be to use `unique=True` on two attributes simultaneously. Is that possible?

Thanks.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Yes, use [unique_together](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/models/options/#unique-together):

```
class Like(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    post = models.ForeignKey(Post)
    time = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    class Meta:
        unique_together = ('user', 'post')
```

Answer (score 22):

[`unique_together`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/models/options/#unique-together) will be deprecated in the future version, instead you could apply `UniqueConstraint`. [This](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/models/constraints/#django.db.models.UniqueConstraint) and [this link](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/models/options/#django.db.models.Options.constraints)  gives example code.

```
class Like(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    post = models.ForeignKey(Post)
    time = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    class Meta:
        constraints = [
            models.UniqueConstraint(fields=['user', 'post'], name='unique_user_post'),
        ]
```